# Javascript objects: How do I make the value of a key be another key (not the key's value)?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a way to programmatically set the value of a key to another key? e.g.

```js
export function getObjectForMapStateToProps(state, reducer) {
    let stateObject = {};
    for (let key in state[reducer]) {
        if (state[reducer].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            stateObject[key] = state[reducer][key];
        }
    }
    return stateObject;
}
```

The goal is for this to return an object where each key, value pair is like so:

```
namespace: state.city.namespace
```

What I am actually getting is the VALUE of the state.city.namespace key:

```
namespace: 'DIskieisSi98s8sjw'.
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT -- ADDING ADDITIONAL CONTEXT**

@mem035 I probably should have added this context. I am trying create a function that will enable me to stop having to type out the mapStateToProps for Redux. For the above example, here is the map:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(getObjectForMapStateToProps(state, 'city'));
    return {
        namespace: state.city.namespace,
        componentId: state.city.componentId,
        items: state.city.items,
        defaultValue: state.city.defaultValue,
        selectItem: state.city.selectItem,
        allowAdd: state.city.allowAdd,
        validationRegEx: state.city.validationRegEx,
        regExDescription: state.city.regExDescription,
        hasForeignKey: state.city.hasForeignKey,
        foreignKeyModel: state.city.foreignKeyModel,
        foreignKeyValue: state.city.foreignKeyValue,
        errorMessages: state.city.errorMessages,
        isError: state.city.isError,
        isLoading: state.city.isLoading,
        apiRoute: state.city.apiRoute
    };
};
```

When the value becomes a string none of the properties are mapping/working.

Comment: `namespace: state.city.namespace` Not sure what you mean by the part on the right there, do you want a string, or what? (strings need to be enclosed in delimiters)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Please see edit--hopefully that context helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just stringify your result instead of again accessing the object.

Instead of:

```
stateObject[key] = state[reducer][key];
```

Use:

```
stateObject[key] = `state.${reducer}.${key}`;
```

Comment: Thanks for that response, but unfortunately that doesn't work. See above edit for additional context.